# Union member as return value

Tags: c

Can a function return a member of a union?

If so, then how should I declare the function's return type and how can I make the return statement in function's definition?

(Actually, I have a series of questions about this, but none of them makes sense unless the previous answered. So this is the first one...)

Comment: A member of a union is just a variable, like a member of a struct is.

Comment: if your union member is an int, you return an int.

Comment: Sorry no code available right now.Actually, I want a union with two members: the one will be the function's "normal" return value and the other will be a value that the function don't want return, if the function fails to do the desired task. E.g., allocating memory for a variable, then the function returns a pointer to that variable, else returns false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. A member of a union is an object. Functions can only return values.

You can return a value that is the value of a member of a union. To do this, the return type of the function is simply the type of the member.

A function can return an entire union (by value). To do this, the return type of the function is the union type.

A function can return some value that tells the caller which member of a union is currently in use (e.g., 0 for the first member and 1 for the second member). To do this, the return type of the function is some type you choose to encode the information (e.g., `int`).

Functions can also return pointers. These are often used as proxies for objects: Since you cannot return an actual object, you return a pointer to an object, and the caller can use the pointer to access the object. A function can return a pointer to a union member or a pointer to a union. (This can be problematic: The object being returned by pointer must be one that continues to exist after the function returns. So it must not be an automatic object created inside the function.)

Comment: I got it. I can use then an enumeration type for the tag field of a union to check the return type, right? But if I want, e.g., a function to return "genuine" value or void (depenting on the function's arguments) then is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: @user32576424: To have a function return either some value *x* or a no-value “void”, you must have a type that can represent both all the desired values *x* and “void” (e.g., pointers can represent both pointers to actual objects and NULL, and floating-point values can represent both numbers and NaN [Not a Number]). Sometimes that is done by setting aside a special value to represent “void”. E.g., if your function never returns negative values for proper results, than -1 could stand for “void”.

Comment: @user3257624: If the basic types are not satisfactory for this, then you can define a struct with two members, one of which tells you whether the return value is “void” or not and the other of which has the actual return value.